# customize height to DHTMLX gantt

Tags: javascript, css, height, gantt-chart, dhtmlx

I have the gantt height in 100% but if the gantt have a lot of information he create a scroll or if have a little information he create a big square with the information and very big space untill the square finish. Any idea, please, Help. What I want is if has a lot of inrfomation dont create the initial scroll or if has little information only draw the neccesary square

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dhtmlxGantt, as for version 2.1, does not have option for automatic sizing. Overall height is always defined by height of container DOM element.

So the only possible option is to handle container height manually, with a custom js code.

**UPDATE:**

Here is a new option of the config, probably it will do the job

http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_autosize_config.html